How do I pass cookies from a server action function to backend?
I'm trying to handle a form submission by using a server action. I need to pass cookies to my backend inside the server action as the cookie contains authentication tokens. But I'm not finding any ways to pass the cookies.
Since the server actions run in the server side there would be no way to read the user's cookie, or am I misunderstanding something here? Is there a solution for this?
